# Use Future when retrieving data using HttpRequest in Dart

Tags: dart

At the moment I'm using a simple HttpRequest to retrieve a JSON file:

```dart
void getConfigData(String url) {
  var request = new HttpRequest.get(url, this.onSuccess);
}

void onSuccess(HttpRequest req) {
  JsonObject conf = new JsonObject.fromJsonString(req.responseText);
  MenuItemCollection top_bar = new MenuItemCollection();
  // and parse the JSON data ...
}
```

What I would like to know is if I should be using Futures instead of the callback?

Comment: What do you mean by "should be using Futures instead of the callback" ?

Comment: To elaborate, I'm reading Dart in Action by Chris, the chapter on Futures and so I was wondering if I should get a file from the server using a Future and Completer instead of using the onSuccess callback as shown above. It's about how to do things 'right'.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have the choice between [Future](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Future.html)s or callbacks, this choice is made by the API you are using. Sometimes you have to give a callback like with [HttpRequest.get](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/HttpRequest.html#HttpRequest.get) and sometimes you get a Future like [File.create](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/File.html#create).

Comment: Isn't the issue that on the `HttpRequest` object you now have a choice between `new HttpRequest.get(...)` or `new HttpRequest().onLoad' which  returns a `Stream`?  The `get` is a shorthand utility, and I don't know if it's going to be re-written to use Streams.